# $ service apache2 restart [fail]

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have installed Apache on my Ubuntu Server. 
For a special reason I have to enable mod_rewrite on it.
So I have done this.

And in every Tutorial on the internet the last command is to restart apache.
But when I do this the console prints `[fail].`

Can anyone help me here?

```
$ service apache2 restart 
 * Restarting web server apache2      [fail]
```

Comment: Log into the error log …

Comment: error.log from /var/log/apache2/ is empty.

Comment: I don't think you can restart services without root access.

Comment: Add `sudo` before the the command.

Comment: I ran into a problem where this happened after I created a sudo user account and I thought it was an update but I ran sudo deluser --remove-all-files "username" and after a lot of warnings I restarted the computer logged in as root and it restarted fine using sudo service apache2 restart. The warnings are about proc files but they are something freed from memory after the ram is refreshed I'm assuming.

Comment: Yes - sudo required!

Answer (score 81):

I had a similar problem, and for me it was about the logged in user not having privileges so instead of

```
service apache2 restart
```

I had to do

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Lol, this makes no sense. We can still do `service apache2 stop` and then `service apache2 start` without `sudo`

Answer (score 47):

It's telling you some other service is already on port 80, perhaps it's apache

try Code:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

followed by Code:

```
sudo killall apache2
```

then make sure no services are running on port 80 Code:

```
sudo netstat -l|grep www
```

then (re)start apache Code:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the systemd features ( starting from Ubuntu 15) , you can restart apache service as follow :

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Check the status:

```
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
```

Answer (score 4):

There are various reason for this one .

1. could be the privilege problem if you have privilege problem then
   please use sudo for the same .
2. could be the apache already running in your system then please check the 
   status of the service by running command `service apache2 status` if they 
   said that [FAIL] apache2 is not running ... failed! it mean it is not running 
   you can start by the command `service apache2 start` or `sudo service
   apache2 start`
3. if you having not above problem please look at the `PID` file of
   apache2 by     following command `cat /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid` 
   which will give you the      process ID of the apache it means you
   system accidentally shutdown without    deleting the `PID` file so
   delete by following command `rm - rf/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid` or `sudo rm -rf/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid`     and start again the server by
   following command `service apache2 start` or `sudo service
   apache2 start`

Answer (score 1):

I face this issue when I was adding new web site to my web server which is hosted in Digital Ocean Cloud service.  So what happened was, when I using sudo commands to restart or reload apache2 server its restring with following error messages.

For me everything worked well despite these two  error messages.

1. Error 1 - Unable to resolve host 'YOUR HOST NAME'  .
2. Error 2 - sum_functio_error() //I don't remember this function name I'll update this later.

So the fix was very simple.

First open your hotsts file.

sudo nano /etc/hosts

Output File

127.0.1.1 hostname
127.0.0.1 localhost

sudo nano /etc/hostname

Output File

hostnamexxx

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try below command to restart.

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

**OR**

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

**OR**

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

To **stop Apache 2** web server, enter:

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

**OR**

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

**OR**

```
$ sudo service apache2 stop
```

---

To **start Apache 2** web server, enter:

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

**OR**

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

**OR**

```
$ sudo service apache2 start
```